# Why arr[idx,:] (for 2D arrays) considered a good methodology

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

A lot of python snippets using `numpy` are using `arr[idx,:]` notation when the array is 2D.
e.g

```
gradPred = -outputVectors[target,:] * (1 - r_W_prob[target])
gradPred += np.dot(r_W_prob[negative_samples], outputVectors[negative_samples, :])
```

I have two followup questions:
a) Is there a difference betwenn `outputVectors[target,:]` and just `outputVectors[target]`?
b) If there is a difference, Is there a "prefered way" to operate, or it's context dependent?
Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't quite correct. Python arrays don't use this notation, it's `numpy` arrays that allow this notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Readability.**

Semantically, the two notations are the *same* for 2D arrays (they both return a 1D array). *However*, the `outputVectors[target, :]` makes it *more clear* that the array is 2D, and that what is returned is 1D.

If `outputVectors` was 1D, you would use `outputVectors[target]` to return a scalar (if you'll notice, that's exactly what `r_W_prob[target]` is, in your code).

Comment: "they both return a row vector": no, they return a 1d array.

Comment: A 1d array has no orientation (try transposing it). It's as much a column vector as a row vector. Semantically a row vector would have shape `(1,n)`.